# Remove Element in Swift linked list

Tags: swift

For a Node class

```
public class ListNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return val.description + (next?.description ?? "")
    }
         public var val: Int
         public var next: ListNode?
         public init(_ val: Int) {
                 self.val = val
                     self.next = nil
             }
     }
```

with a head and nodes such that

```
let head = ListNode(4)
let second = ListNode(5)
let third = ListNode(1)
let forth = ListNode(8)
head.next = second
second.next = third
third.next = forth
forth.next = nil
```

We can remove the second node simply with

```
head.next = third
```

Will second be deallocated and the memory freed up?

Or do we need to remove the reference from second such that

```
second.next = nil
```

Comment: not sure if it is deallocated when `nil` is assigned, but it is not going to be deallocated if nothing is done

Comment: Change `let` to `var` and set `second = nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually observe the deinitialisations, we can add a `deinit` block to `ListNode`:

```
deinit {
    print("\(val) deinit")
}
```

Your current code will not cause anything to be deinitialised, because recall that objects are only deinitialised when no other object holds a reference to it. In your current code, the global scope still has the `let` constant `second` that holds a reference to the second node, even after `head.next = third` is executed. This causes the second node to not be deinitialised.

One way to cause the second node to deinitialise, then, is to remove all the `let` constants except `head`:

```
let head = ListNode(4)
head.next = ListNode(5) // second
head.next?.next = ListNode(1) // third
head.next?.next?.next = ListNode(8) // fourth
```

And then removing the second node:

```
head.next = head.next?.next
```

This causes the following to be printed:

```
5 deinit
```

indicating that the second node is deinitialised.

Setting `second.next` to nil is irrelevant here, as `second.next` holds a reference to the *third* node. Setting it to nil only decreases the number of references pointing to the third node, making an effort toward deinitialising the third node.